# Java Regex Email replacing all Whitespaces and "[at]" sign

Tags: java, email

I have a method that  uses regular expression to validate an Email adress.

```
public String searchFormail(String searchWord) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})");
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+  \\(at\\)([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");

    Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(searchWord);
    Matcher matchs2 = pattern2.matcher(searchWord);

    if (matchs.find() || matchs2.find()) {
        return searchWord.substring(matchs.start(), matchs.end());

    }

    return null;
}
```

First Question: If `searchFormail` gets this string as input "support@ google.com" , notice the whitespace after @. How can I replace this whitespace so that the string input becomes "support@google.com". I tried `//s`  inside of regex, but that justs ignores whitespaces. So, that does not help.

Second Question: My second pattern, which validates mails with "google[at]support.com" does not work. How can improve this regex in order to get emails like "google[at]support.com" so that it becomes "google@support.com", like transforming "[at]" to @.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question: Actually a mail address never allows whitespaces, so I would simply remove all whitespaces by something like

`searchWord = searchWord.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Second Question: Your `pattern2` includes whitespaces `([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+_HERE_ARE_WHITESPACES_\\(at\\)([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})`.
Thus it does not find a mail address.

Furthermore your pattern looks for a email format like "google(at)support.com" rather then "google[at]support.com".

To replace the "(at)" with an actual "@" you adapt your pattern2 and use the replaceFirst method.
This is the full code that works for me. I hope it helps.

```
public static String searchFormail(String searchWord) {

    searchWord = searchWord.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})");
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+)(\\(at\\))(([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");

    Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(searchWord);
    Matcher matchs2 = pattern2.matcher(searchWord);

    if(matchs.find()){
        return searchWord.substring(matchs.start(), matchs.end());
    }
    else if(matchs2.find()){
        return matchs2.replaceFirst("$1@$4");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much